# How to export a TypeScript class in a way that won't disrupt accessing the object using plain old vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Forgive my ignorance on this, I'm stuck and hoping to get some guided direction.

Take this `Greeter` class example found on TypeScript's [playground page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html):

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}
```

I've been tasked to build and manage a single component that can be used both in a plain HTML + JavaScript environment, but also in an Angular application. I'm managing / writing this code in TypeScript, and using TypeScript to compile the output as JavaScript.

Referring back to the above example, if I wanted to make that class available (as an import) in Angular, I would need to export the class?

```
export class Greeter {
    ...
}
```

When I do that, the page throws errors:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined`

The compiled JavaScript looks like this:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var Greeter = /** @class */ (function () {
        function Greeter(message) {
            this.greeting = message;
        }
        Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
            return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
        };
        return Greeter;
    }());
    exports.Greeter = Greeter;
    var greeter = new Greeter("world");
});
```

Because the Greeter class is now bound to that define block, I obviously can't instantiate a new class as such:

`let greeter = new Greeter("world"); // < -- Won't work.`

**Throws error:**

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Greeter is not defined`

1. How would I go about exporting that class, in a way that won't disrupt accessing the object in say a vanilla JavaScript fashion?
2. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?
3. Is this a reasonable goal, or am I completely on the wrong track here?

Comment: `define` appears in Playground because it defaults to AMD module. This won't be so in real code and depends on what `module` compiler option is set to. How exactly is the code associated with Angular? Is it Angular or AngularJS, first of all? Do you use this file in Angular project source files? In this case it will be compiled as other files. Do you export it as NPM package?

Comment: It's Angular, not AngularJS. As far as using it with Angular, not quite there yet but the idea is that yes, I would like to import the file and then define it as a component. For now, not an NPM package but the same idea applies, include a common JS bundle somewhere in the root app, refer to it or import it and use it in the app.

Comment: This is one of numerous problems that you'll have to solve when setting up Angular app from scratch. As a rule of thumb, Angular applications use Angular CLI for scaffolding and building. It already has TS configured for you. An alternative is to use a boilerplate project, which again already has TS configured for you. For practical purposes you can stick to them and learn from how things are done there. You can learn from official Angular plunk which of course contains TS configuration, http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5

Answer (score 3):

Good question, what you're asking is definitely reasonable.

First of all it's worth mentioning that what you are referring to as "vanilla JavaScript" is ES5 with AMD module library compatibility. ES6 introduced native language-level modules to JavaScript, which is what the `export` and `import` syntax is.

TypeScript has a [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) `--module` which lets you choose what module target to compile for and produce output for. However in the case of external module systems, like `AMD` and `CommonJS`, it does not actually output the module system required to make it work, it's just emitting JavaScript that's compatible with those systems. It's up to you to include the module system, such as [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org), or run in an environment that has built in support, like NodeJS' CommonJS module system. If you set the `--module` target to `es6` you'll see it leaves the `export` statements as is, and this would work in a browser that supports ES6 modules (assuming the import path resolves to a file the browser can access).

Also worth mentioning is that with JavaScript bundlers like Webpack or Browserify, you can take practically any module output from TypeScript and bundle it for the browser without the need to introduce a module runtime yourself, because the bundler takes care of it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron, appreciate the feedback! Super helpful. Will take all these points into consideration and refactor things accordingly.